# Apply grouping to custom views list template

Tags: views, theming, entities

I have a custom `views-view-list.tpl.php` template that uses

```
foreach ($view->style_plugin->rendered_fields as $delta => $item)
```

to manipulate the fields at this template level rather than using

```
foreach ($rows as $id => $row)
```

and relying on `views-view-fields.tpl.php` to render the HTML.

However, when using grouping in a view, the `views-view-list.tpl.php` is called once for each grouping, but the first method renders all items, rather than just the ones in the current grouping.

**How can I tell from `views-view-list.tpl.php` which items belong to the current grouping?**

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the `$rows` object has indices that don't go from 0, counting up by 1.  It keeps only indices of the items in the current group.  That makes this code work:

```
<?php foreach ($view->style_plugin->rendered_fields as $delta => $item): ?>
    <?php if(isset($rows[$delta])) : ?>
         ... print out whatever necessary ...
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```